# Listening to multiple ports and Accepting connections

Tags: c, server, httprequest

This is a sample of my code. I have created two sockets, opened two ports and trying to accept connections. All my file descriptors are set to `NONBLOCK`.

The file descriptor `fd_client_serv` is used for accepting HTTP GET requests in port 8080.

The file descriptor `fd_client_comm` is used for accepting commands on my server from a client in port 9090.

When I send an HTTP request I want to read the request and simply print the first line. But sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. While the server is running, I am using curl to send the request. Sometimes server proceeds to print the message and sometimes not. I am guessing that there is a problem with double `accepting`.

Could you give me some help?

```
while(1)
{
    if((fd_client_serv = accept(fd_serv, (struct sockaddr *) &client_serv_addr, &sin_len_serv)) != -1)
    {
        new_fd = fd_client_serv;
        fd_set_blocking(new_fd, 0);
    }
    if((fd_client_comm = accept(fd_comm, (struct sockaddr *) &client_comm_addr, &sin_len_comm)) != -1)
    {
        temp = fd_client_comm;
        fd_set_blocking(temp, 0);
    }

    if (temp != 0)
    {
        if (server_commands(fd_comm, temp, start_time) == 1)
            break;
    }
    if (new_fd != 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        while ((bytes_read = read(new_fd, &(message[i]), 1)) != -1)
        {
            if (message[i] == '\n')
                break;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%s\n", message);
        write(new_fd, "return message", 14);
        memset(message, 0, 100);
        close(new_fd);
        new_fd = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless the listening socket is set non-blocking, the `accept()` function *blocks* until a connection is accepted.  Even if your listening sockets were non-blocking, you would have a performance-munching busy loop.  Thus, although having two `accept()` calls per loop iteration is not *inherently* wrong, you're unlikely to be able to make them work well together.

Instead, consider one of these alternatives:

- fork a separate child process to handle each port your application services, or
- service each port with a separate thread, or
- use `select()`, `poll()`, or similar to multiplex I/O handling for multiple ports and / or multiple simultaneous clients.